# Defining a color as a static resource

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-4.0

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
...
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="MyColor">#FFEEDD</Color>
    <Color x:Key="MyOtherColor">Green</Color>
    <!-- Use MyColor and MyOtherColor to define other resources... -->
  </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

Unfortunately, I am forced to do this instead:

```
...
<Grid>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="MyColor" A="255" R="255" G="238" B="221" />
    <Color x:Key="MyOtherColor" A="255" R="0" G="128" B="0" />
    <!-- Use MyColor and MyOtherColor to define other resources... -->
  </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

Because, it seems that value converters are not kicking in. This is a royal pain in the rump and I was wondering what I can do, so that I can define my colors symbolically and by hex value?

Comment: I've only ever seen the first way. I didn't even know you could do it the second way.

Comment: Looks like the problem was due to a build issue, where the VS2010 designer was out of sync with the XAML. Thanks to Meleak for testing it out in a separate project.

Comment: @Gabe: I changed it from the first to the second way. What I didn't realize was that I did a rebuild in between, which fixed the issue which was apparently limited to the VS2010 designer. If I had just done a full rebuild without changing the XAML, it would have worked the first way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. I tried this and it's working. How are you using your Color Resources?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="MyColor">#FFEEDD</Color>
        <Color x:Key="MyOtherColor">Green</Color>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Rectangle>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource MyColor}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That's odd, it seems to work now. I wonder if this was a rebuild issue. I am going to mark your answer as answered and close the question. Thanks...